# Adding the time stamps using shell/awk scripts

Tags: shell

I have following data in a text file i.e time field: 00:26:15

```
00:01:33
00:02:20
00:04:33
00:00:45
00:01:33
00:02:16
00:06:29
00:08:16
00:26:15
00:01:33
00:02:20
00:04:33
00:00:45
00:01:33
00:02:16
00:06:29
00:08:16
```

How do i add them and take out an average using awk or shell?

The output should be total time = $total
Average time = $avg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the list into file `file`:

```
cat <<EOF >file
00:01:33
00:02:20
00:04:33
00:00:45
00:01:33
00:02:16
00:06:29
00:08:16
00:26:15
00:01:33
00:02:20
00:04:33
00:00:45
00:01:33
00:02:16
00:06:29
00:08:16
EOF
```

I canto the following:

```
# convert each line to seconds. using stream and date.
to_seconds=$(<file xargs -i date -d"1970-01-01 {}Z" +%s)
# sum of seconds
sum=$(<<<"$to_seconds" tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$/\n/' | bc)
# convert seconds into HH:MM:SS
sec_to_time() { echo "$(($1/3600)):$(($1%3600/60)):$(($1%60))"; }
sum_time=$(sec_to_time "$sum")
# number of lines in the file
lines=$(<file wc -l)
# avarage is the sum divided by the number of lines
avg=$(<<<"$sum / $lines" bc)
# convert avg into time
avg_time=$(sec_to_time "$avg")
# output
echo "sum $sum_time"
echo "avg $avg_time"
```

I will output:

```
sum 1:21:45
avg 0:4:48
```

We could also do an advanced oneliner with a bit of `tee` and synchronization:

```
exec 3<> >(:)
avg=$(
        # convert to seconds
        <file xargs -i date -d"1970-01-01 {}Z" +%s |
        # calculate the sum
        tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$/\n/' | bc |
        # tee - output sum to 3 file descriptor
        tee >(sec_to_time "$(cat)" >&3) |
        # calculate avarage and convert to time
        echo "$(cat) / $(<file wc -l)" | bc | 
        sec_to_time "$(cat)"
)
# just to be sure, timeout the background job with a... timeout
sum=$(timeout 1 head -n1 <&3)
exec 3<&-
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil, can you explain these lines in much deatail to_seconds=$(<file xargs -i date -d"1970-01-01 {}Z" +%s)
# sum of seconds
sum=$(<<<"$to_seconds" tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$/\n/' | bc)
# convert seconds into HH:MM:SS
sec_to_time() { echo "$(($1/3600)):$(($1%3600/60)):$(($1%60))"; }

Comment: `<file` - read the file and append it to commands standard input (stdin). `xargs -i` - for each line from `stdin` run the command and substitute `{}` for the line. `date -d"1970-01-01 {}Z" +%s` - will be run for each line, with the `{}` substituted for the line. You can use `-t` option to `xargs` to see what is executed.

Comment: `<<<"$to_seconds` -- that's a herestring, like `<file` but with variables. `tr '\n' '+'` - substitute newline for `+` sign. `sed 's/+$/\n/'` - as after `tr` it will look like `1+2+3+4+` we need to remove the last `+` from the stream. Also add a newline. `bc` - is a calculator, it adds numbers, ie. `echo 1+2+3 | bc` -> 6.

Comment: `sec_to_time() { echo "$(($1/3600)):$(($1%3600/60)):$(($1%60))"; }` it's pretty self-explenatory. It's a function, $1 is the first parameter to the function, `$((...))` does calculations to get from sum of seconds get the hours, minutes and seconds... ie. divide by 60, divide by 3600, get the rest of division by 60 etc. | You can always add `set -x` to bash scripts to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Save these times to 'file' and then run this:

```
cat file | tr "\n" " " | tr -s " " | awk -F ' ' '{ for(a = 1; a <= NF; a ++){ split($a, t, ":"); total += t[1]*3600 + t[2]*60 + t[3] } a = total/NF; printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", a/3600, a%3600/60, a%3600%60) }'
```

First command will read 'file', second will remove newlines. Awk will separate these times from stdin, summarize seconds and in the end convert secknds to `%H:%M:%S` format.

Comment: So i tried it it gives me 00:51:00 which i believe is the average right?

Comment: 00:26:15
00:01:33
00:02:20
00:04:33
00:00:45
00:01:33
00:02:16
00:06:29
00:08:16
00:26:15
00:01:33
00:02:20
00:04:33
00:00:45
00:01:33
00:02:16
00:06:29
00:08:16.....my data is like this....for some reason i think the total i am getting is wrong can you please copy this to a text file and run the same and check?Please copy this data column wise as i have it in that format i.e 00:26:15 followed by 00:01:33 in next line..

Comment: @MfjoneZ I got it, you used dataset separated with newlines, try it again, I edited code. :)

Comment: great working now...thanks..but it's quite a lengthy command :)